# Remove ID field from PDF with Apache PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I need to compare to PDF documents which habe been created with iText. I actually managed to compare the documents but I'm stumbling over a tiny difference.

When opening the PDFs in an editor like Notepad++ I can see that there is something like this towares the end of the file:

```
/Root 1 0 R
/ID [<Some ID here> <Some other ID here>]
```

As I have found out here ([What is the ID field in a pdf file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085899/what-is-the-id-field-in-a-pdf-file)) this element belongs to something called "Trailer".

Can I access and modify this "field" with the Apache PDFBox?

Comment: It seems that you're comparing files generated using the same code on a binary level. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897806/why-would-pdfs-generated-by-the-same-automated-process-be-different-on-different/23905287#23905287 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039691/reason-why-pdf-files-have-differences/ to find out why this is a bad idea. A simple change of JVM can result in a different order of keys in a PDF dictionary. A slight optimization of the compression algorithm and the files are different. And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet works fine for me.

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdf);
COSArray cosArray = doc.getDocument().getDocumentID();
// Clear or set whatever values...
cosArray.clear();
doc.getDocument().setDocumentID(cosArray);
```

Comment: can you provide more explanations on why it works for you?

Comment: Using cosArray.clear() followed by doc.getDocument().setDocumentID(cosArray) I can set the value for the ID as asked in my original question.